# Using Linq.js with Durandal/Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, linq.js, weyland

I have done the following setup:

1. Added the following script tag:

   ```
   <script src="Scripts/linq.js"></script>
   ```
2. Configure linq.js in the main.js

   ```
   requirejs.config({
   paths: {
       'text': '../Scripts/text',
       'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
       'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
       'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
       'knockout': '../Scripts/knockout-2.3.0',
       'jquery': '../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1,',        
       'linq': '../Scripts/linq'
   }
   // The ko in this project is already AMD
   , shim: {        
       linq : {
           exports: 'Enumerable'
       }
   }   
    });
   ```
3. Attempt to get a copy of it in one of my viewmodel (shell.js) like this:

   ```
   define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app','linq'], function (router, app, linq)
   ```
4. Optimizing the build using weyland, however I'm getting:

> Error 1   ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'C:\Project\build\App\linq.js'    C:\Project\

I'm new to this, did I get anything wrong?

I thought the shim should point to the global variable, which I did.

Do I need to create my own define in addition to the shim? I thought Shim is supposed to be a syntactic sugar wrapper over define over a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shim shouldn't be required in this situation, where `linq` is include via script tag. Just make sure load `linq` via script tag before  loading `main.js` via require.js. Next remove the configuration entries and the dependency.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'knockout': '../Scripts/knockout-2.3.0',
        'jquery': '../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1,'
        }
    }   
});


define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app){...
```

That way there's no need to configure weyland to exclude it.

Comment: Rainer, I prefer to have requirejs includes it where possible, then referencing the script directly. Removing the script tag leads to a different error (as it attempts to resolve 'linq'): "Failed to load composed module (viewmodels/shell). Details: Script error for: linq
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror"

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal dFiddle (https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I pulled the script out of the path information and have it be loaded by the page. That seems to do the trick. Although still very much unclear about when I wanna use shim, and if it's appropriate in this case. But problem for another time.